# How can I configure IPython 5 to have IPython 3's readline, tab-completion, (lack-of) syntax highlighting, etc? (self.IPython)

Tags: python, configuration, ipython

I know at some point I may want to "upgrade", but for now I just want the old look & feel back.

I know IPython is very configurable but I'm not having much luck finding the correct settings.

(This only refers to IPython's interactive terminal, by the way)

Comment: You can [configure](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/intro.html) `TerminalInteractiveShell.display_completions = 'readlinelike'` and `InteractiveShell.colors = 'NoColor'`. It won't actually switch back to readline, but it will make it look more like the old interface.

Comment: I, for one, cannot fathom why they changed the the tab-completion away from the "readlinelike" option. I can't see how it's supposed to be better having to scroll through a bunch of stuff to get the information you're looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start by creating a default iPython profile. From your shell, type:

```
$ ipython profile create
```

That should give output similar to this, assuming the username `someuser`:

```
[ProfileCreate] Generating default config file: u'/home/someuser/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py'
```

Open the newly created file with your favorite text editor, in the above example shown as: `/home/someuser/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py`

Add the following lines at the bottom:

```
c.TerminalInteractiveShell.colors = 'NoColor'
c.TerminalInteractiveShell.display_completions = 'readlinelike'
```

Save the file.

That should be it. Changes should be active in new iPython sessions.